# Kubernetes vagrant error on restarting: Can't find the necessary components for the parallels vagrant provider

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, kubernetes

I got this errors when restarting or reinstalling Kubernetes, any clue how to solve them:

... calling verify-prereqs
Can't find the necessary components for the parallels vagrant provider.
Possible reasons could be: 
    - vmrun utility is not in your path
    - Vagrant plugin was not found.
    - VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER is set, but not found.
Please fix and retry.

Comment: Have you checked what the message says? What's your workflow?

Comment: It's been resolved. The problem was not putting the right the default provider in 'export DEFAULT_PROVIDER = ...". Putting 'virtualbox' solved the problem. What are the other DEFAULT_PROVIDERS possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [cluster/vagrant/util.sh](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/vagrant/util.sh#L46-L56), the possible providers are: vmware_fusion, vmware_workstation, parallels, virtualbox, libvirt, vsphere.